# a href keeps adding local file path to URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having a bit of difficulty here. I am trying to set an `<a>` tag to an external URL. But each time I do so, the local path to the index.html which contains the URL is added to the link. I have looked at my jQuery code and don't seem to see what the problem is. I have even used console.log(url) to test and it returns the URL properly.

```js
$('.smoothscroll').on("click", function() {
    if (nav.hasClass('mobile')) nav.fadeOut('fast');
})

$('.smoothscroll').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var target = this.hash,
    $target = $(target);

    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
    }, 800, 'swing', function () {
        window.location.hash = target;
    });
});
    
$('#login').on('click', function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    window.open(url, '_blank');
});
```

```html
<ul id="nav" class="nav">
    <li class="current"><a class="smoothscroll" href="#hero">Home.</a></li>
     <!--<li><a class="smoothscroll" href="#portfolio">Works.</a></li>-->
  <li><a class="smoothscroll" href="#about">About Us.</a></li>
    <li><a class="smoothscroll" href="#portfolio">Features.</a></li>
    <li><a class="smoothscroll" href="#contact">Create Account.</a></li>
    <li><a class="login" id="login" href="google.com">Login.</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Each time the new URL opens in a new tab, this is what i get: file:///C:/PASSIS%20-%20Landing%20Page/google.com

[image: Local File Path Added To URL]

Comment: Make sure you have `http://` or `https://`. That sometimes causes the issue.

Comment: Exactly right. Add the protocol.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For external URLs you need to have the protocol (`http://` or `https://`) to let the HTML know that it is an external resource/site and not a local resource.

Answer (score 2):

That confused me once too. The solution is quiet simple, just add the protocol type to the link, e.g:

```
<a href="https://google.com">Google</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `https://` (`http://`) protocol before `google.com`, because you are not pointing to local file, but to external page:

```
<a class="login" id="login" href="https://google.com">Login.</a>
```

Comment: Thanks. Can't believe something as simple as this, would give me such problems.